# why there is just egg-info without actual modules when I use pip install beautifulsoup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, pip, egg

I used the command `pip install beautifulsoup4` to install beautifulsoup, however, after I tried to import it and failed I found something interesting, there is just egg-info folder but no scripts folder, can anybody tell me why and how to solve this? I know I can just get the script and move it to sitepackages folder and I did like that and it works but I feel it's bad idea.

Comment: There should also be a `bs4` folder in `site-packages`, is it there? How were you trying to import it? It should be `import bs4`.

Comment: Yes, I found it! I thought that it should have something like beautifulsoup4 folder, which cause me automatically ignored the short names...thank you. I imported it like `from BeautifulSoup import *` but now probably just `from bs4 import *`, right?

Comment: @litaoshen: up to BeautifulSoup *3* you'd import from the `BeautifulSoup` module, but BeautifulSoup 4 switched to the `bs4` package instead.

Comment: @MartijnPieters see comment above, thank you Martijn

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you install `beautifulsoup4` with `pip`, you are installing a *distribution* by that name. The `.egg-info` folder `pip` creates when installing that distribution is named after the distribution (plus the version and python architecture).

The distribution contains one or more packages or modules, and these are installed into the `site-packages` folder *next* to the `.egg-info` directory. The names of these packages or modules do not necessarily correspond to the distribution name.

For BeautifulSoup 4, the distribution contains one package named `bs4`.

You can verify this for yourself; inside the `.egg-info` directory is a file named `installed-files.txt`, listing all associated files (using relative paths):

```
$ cat lib/python2.7/site-packages/beautifulsoup4*.egg-info/installed-files.txt
../bs4/__init__.py
../bs4/dammit.py
../bs4/diagnose.py
../bs4/element.py
../bs4/testing.py
../bs4/builder/__init__.py
../bs4/builder/_html5lib.py
../bs4/builder/_htmlparser.py
../bs4/builder/_lxml.py
../bs4/tests/__init__.py
../bs4/tests/test_builder_registry.py
../bs4/tests/test_docs.py
../bs4/tests/test_html5lib.py
../bs4/tests/test_htmlparser.py
../bs4/tests/test_lxml.py
../bs4/tests/test_soup.py
../bs4/tests/test_tree.py
../bs4/__init__.pyc
../bs4/dammit.pyc
../bs4/diagnose.pyc
../bs4/element.pyc
../bs4/testing.pyc
../bs4/builder/__init__.pyc
../bs4/builder/_html5lib.pyc
../bs4/builder/_htmlparser.pyc
../bs4/builder/_lxml.pyc
../bs4/tests/__init__.pyc
../bs4/tests/test_builder_registry.pyc
../bs4/tests/test_docs.pyc
../bs4/tests/test_html5lib.pyc
../bs4/tests/test_htmlparser.pyc
../bs4/tests/test_lxml.pyc
../bs4/tests/test_soup.pyc
../bs4/tests/test_tree.pyc
./
dependency_links.txt
PKG-INFO
SOURCES.txt
top_level.txt
```